# Difference between editionable and editioning views?

Tags: oracle, view

In the syntax diagram of create view we see  three ways for create:

> [image: Blockquote]

- `EDITIONING`
- `EDITIONABLE EDITIONING`
- `NONEDITIONABLE`

What is the difference between `create editioning` and `create editionable editioning`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These clauses relate to [Edition-based redefinition](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/high-availability/ebr.html).

This introduces the concept of an edition. This extends the namespace for objects in Oracle Database. So the fully qualified name of an object is now

`edition_name.schema_name.object_name`

So one object can have many definitions in the same schema. The `edition_name` is part of your session's settings; you can't specify it directly.

Editioning views are a special type of view used to support zero-downtime schema changes. You place these on your tables and change the application code to access these views instead of the base tables. They are subject to a [number of restrictions](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30__GUID-E89B1B60-CBCB-4C3F-B30C-6B24B7CBD15B):

> - Within any edition, you can create only one editioning view for any single table.
> - You cannot specify the object_view_clause, XMLType_view_clause, or BEQUEATH clause.
> - You cannot define a constraint WITH CHECK OPTION on an editioning view.
> - In the select list of the defining subquery, you can specify only simple references to the columns of the base table, and you can
>   specify each column of the base table only once in the select list.
>   The asterisk wildcard symbol * and t_alias.* are supported to
>   designate all columns of a base table.
> - The FROM clause of the defining subquery of the view can reference only a single existing database table. Joins are not permitted. The
>   base table must be in the same schema as the view being created. You
>   cannot use a synonym to identify the table, but you can specify a
>   table alias.
> - The following clauses of the defining subquery are not valid for editioning views: subquery_factoring_clause, DISTINCT or UNIQUE,
>   where_clause, hierarchical_query_clause, group_by_clause, HAVING
>   condition, model_clause, or the set operators (UNION, INTERSECT, or
>   MINUS)

You can create `cross-edition triggers` on `editioning` views. You use these to maintain columns present in one edition but not another.

The `editionable`/`noneditionable` keywords apply to regular views. They define whether each edition can have its own version of a view (it's `editionable`) or if all editions must have the same edition of the view (it's `noneditionable`)